# Trying to set attr to disabled when a textfield is hidden?

Tags: jquery, hidden-field

I am using the jquery-interdepencies library with a form and i like the hidden textfields and/or textfield without a value to not being sent/handled on submit. To accomplish this i have to set disabled to true

```
$('#testform :input:hidden').attr('disabled', true);
```

I guess the jquery-interdepencies lib prevents this, but i can't see how i can fix this. I think jquery-interdepencies set the input fields to display: none

btw: how important is it to have hidden or empty textfield not being sent to a form handler

[jqyery lib link](http://miohtama.github.io/jquery-interdependencies/docs/#!/api/Rule)

Comment: Why do you use ``attr('disabled', true)``? Instead try ``attr('disabled','disabled')`` or ``prop('disabled', true)``.

Comment: @heroin tried all three :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs for this plug-in, you can add callbacks for when you show or hide elements. So something like this will work:

```
var cfg = {
    hide: function(elem) {
        elem.hide();
        elem.find('input').attr('disabled','disabled');
    },
    show: function(elem) {
        elem.show();
        elem.find('input').attr('disabled',false);
    }
};

// Make the ruleset effective on the whole page
ruleset.install(cfg);
```

**Problem**: when I tested this out, I found a [bug in the plugin which I have raised on github](https://github.com/miohtama/jquery-interdependencies/issues/11).

So you can copy/paste the entire fixed plugin from [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d10s1bfc/2/) if you wish. It demos how the elements are disabled when hidden.

Comment: hmm that looks promising. Could you "learn" me how to configure this? Simply adding your code didn't work, i am trying to   add your var cfg to my existing ruleset 
` ruleset.install({log: true, show:cfg, hide:cfg});`

Comment: Edited and fiddle added.

Comment: i am having a little problem when i use nested checkboxes combined with an option menu. I am not able to set the option menu to none selected if one of the parent checkboxes is deselected http://jsfiddle.net/wesweatyoushop/d10s1bfc/13/